# Using XPath functions in libxml

Tags: xpath, libxml2, xml-libxml

I am trying to evaluate certain XPath expressions with [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/index.html) 2.8.0 and am getting error messages with functions. It is not clear to me whether libxml implements the whole or a subset of the XPath specification. Is there any resource clearly identifying what is implemented and how to use it?

In my specific case, one expression I am trying to evaluate is:

```
/TemporalInformation/RecipeInformation[fn:exists(./ActionToActionRelation[fn:contains(./@actionA,'cook') and fn:exists(./IngredientA[fn:contains(./@classes,'onion')])])]
```

I am using libxml through the XML::LibXML Perl module, but I have also tried my expression with [the `xpath1.c` example](http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/#xpath1.c) tool available from xmlsoft.org, and got the same error messages:

```
$ ./xpath-tester data/fk.xml "/TemporalInformation/RecipeInformation[fn:exists(.> /ActionToActionRelation[fn:contains(./@actionA,'cook') and fn:exists(./IngredientA[fn:contains(./@classes,'onion')])])]" "fn=http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
xmlXPathCompOpEval: function contains not found
XPath error : Unregistered function
xmlXPathCompOpEval: function exists not found
XPath error : Unregistered function
XPath error : Invalid expression
XPath error : Stack usage errror
Error: unable to evaluate xpath expression "/TemporalInformation/RecipeInformation[fn:exists(./ActionToActionRelation[fn:contains(./@actionA,'cook') and fn:exists(./IngredientA[fn:contains(./@classes,'onion')])])]"
Usage: ./xpath-tester <xml-file> <xpath-expr> [<known-ns-list>]
where <known-ns-list> is a list of known namespaces
in "<prefix1>=<href1> <prefix2>=href2> ..." format
```

I have tried with and without the `fn` namespace, both with `xpath.c` and my Perl script, and got the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `libxml` XPath implementation is only XPath 1.0, so 2.0-only functions such as `exists` aren't available.  In 1.0 you only have a few [core functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#corelib) - there's `starts-with` but not `ends-with`, no regular expression support, no date handling, etc. and there's no strong typing and none of the higher-level constructs like `if` and `for`.

So to answer your question, yes, it *does* support the whole of XPath, but only XPath 1.0.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Since it gave an error message for `contains` as well, this hadn't occured to me. After testing, I confirm the error message for `contains` disappears if the expression is not using `exists`. Strange enough!

Comment: @scozy it will complain about `fn:contains` but not about `contains` without the `fn:` prefix.  As far as XPath 1.0 is concerned, `fn:contains` is an unknown extension function rather than a core function.